# Get selected file or folder in windows explorer

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

Does anybody know a way how to get a selected file/folder in explorer's active window.
I looked through Shell API section in MSDN but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: For what purpose? The solution will depend on what is appropriate for your usage.

Comment: Here is a similar question which may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382946/get-selected-items-of-folder-with-winapi/3400348#3400348