# Error com4j.ComException: 80004005 .\invoke.cpp:51 while getting open windows and selected items

Tags: java, winapi, windows-explorer, shell32, com4j

I need to get all selected files and folders in Windows Explorer. I'm using com4j to access win Shell32 API *(thanks to Tom91136, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835261/2608629) if you need to learn how can you install and initialize com4j)*.

This code class gets the selected files or folders in Windows Explorer and prints.

```
import java.io.File;
import com4j.*;
import test.wsh.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import javax.swing.*;


public class DetectSelection {

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
            list(); //there is a timer actually, calls every second
    }

    public static void list(){
        System.out.println("SELECTION DETECT:");

        String newResults="";

        try
        {
            List<IWebBrowser2> browsers = getIWebBrowser2();
            for(IWebBrowser2 browser : browsers){
                IShellFolderViewDual3 view = getIShellFolderViewDual3(browser);
                if (view != null && browser.visible()) {

                    FolderItems items = view.selectedItems();

                    for (Com4jObject object : items) {
                        FolderItem item = object.queryInterface(FolderItem.class);
                        if (item != null) {
                            newResults+=item.path()+" - "+item.type()+"\n\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in list: "+error.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(newResults);
    }

    public static List<IWebBrowser2> getIWebBrowser2() {
        // TODO this can be potentially optimized
        try
        {
            List<IWebBrowser2> rWindows=new ArrayList<IWebBrowser2>();

            IShellWindows windows = ClassFactory.createShellWindows()
                    .queryInterface(IShellWindows.class);
            for (Com4jObject window : windows) {

                IWebBrowser2 browser = window.queryInterface(IWebBrowser2.class);
                    rWindows.add(browser);
            }
            return rWindows;
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in getIWebBrowser2: "+error.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static IShellFolderViewDual3 getIShellFolderViewDual3(IWebBrowser2 browser) {
        if (browser == null)
            return null;

        try
        {
            return browser.document().queryInterface(IShellFolderViewDual3.class);
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in getIShellFolderViewDual3: "+error.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I posted only essential parts. I am using a timer to check open files periodically. Calls list() method every second. It works fine but I am getting the error below if I close a Window.

```
    com4j.ComException: 80004005 
 .\invoke.cpp:517
        at com4j.Wrapper.invoke(Wrapper.java:166)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.document(Unknown Source)
        at DetectSelection.getIShellFolderViewDual3(DetectSelection.java:79)
        at DetectSelection.list(DetectSelection.java:32)
    Caused by: com4j.ComException: 80004005 Belirtilmemiş hata : Belirtilmemiş hata : .\invoke.cpp:517
        at com4j.Native.invoke(Native Method)
        at com4j.StandardComMethod.invoke(StandardComMethod.java:35)
        at com4j.Wrapper$InvocationThunk.call(Wrapper.java:340)
        at com4j.Task.invoke(Task.java:51)
        at com4j.ComThread.run0(ComThread.java:153)
        at com4j.ComThread.run(ComThread.java:134)
```

I started to use try-catch and I got this:

```
Error in getIShellFolderViewDual3: com4j.ComException: 80004005  .\invoke.cpp:517
```

Something wrong with "IShellFolderViewDual3" method.

Comment: Which version of com4j are you using? Did you compile com4j from source or used the binary distribution?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version and added the jar files into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is about timer. If there is a timer and the list() method is running every second then when you close a window, getIShellFolderViewDual3() method also tries to access a closing window, at the same time.

Check if "browser" object is visible and not null before use it.

```
try
        {
            List<IWebBrowser2> browsers = getIWebBrowser2();
            for(IWebBrowser2 browser : browsers){
                if(browser.visible())
                {

                    IShellFolderViewDual3 view = getIShellFolderViewDual3(browser);
                    if (view != null && browser.visible()) {

                        FolderItems items = view.selectedItems();

                        for (Com4jObject object : items) {
                            FolderItem item = object.queryInterface(FolderItem.class);
                            if (item != null) {
                                newResults+=item.path()+" - "+item.type()+"\n\n";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```