# Get current selection in WindowsExplorer from a delphi application?

Tags: delphi

I read [Get current selection in WindowsExplorer from a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292953/get-current-selection-in-windowsexplorer-from-a-c-sharp-application):

```cs
IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();

List<string> selected = new List<string>();
var shell = new Shell32.Shell();
foreach(SHDocVw.InternetExplorer window in shell.Windows())
{
    if (window.HWND == (int)handle)
    {
        Shell32.FolderItems items = ((Shell32.IShellFolderViewDual2)window.Document).SelectedItems();
        foreach(Shell32.FolderItem item in items)
        {
            selected.Add(item.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

and I try to write it in Delphi:

```pascal
uses
  ActiveX, ComObj, ShlObj;

procedure GetSelectedItems();
var
  ShellFolderView: IShellFolderViewDual;
  aFolderItems: FolderItems;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellFolderView, nil, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IShellFolderView, ShellFolderView));
  .....
end;
```

But the code raises an error:

> no class registered

How should I register the class?

In MSDN, I see  [`IShellFolderViewDual::SelectedItems()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/nf-shldisp-ishellfolderviewdual-selecteditems):

```c
HRESULT SelectedItems(
  [out] FolderItems **ppid
);
```

There is no parameter input.

How do I use `SelectedItems()`?

```pascal
function SelectedItems(var ppid: FolderItems): HRESULT; stdcall;
```

Comment: Errors come with messages to tell you **why** the error happened.

Comment: The C# code creates a Shell object, enumerates its Explorer windows, and grabs the `IShellFolderViewDual2` interface of a specific window.

Your Delphi code is not even attempting to do any of that.

Don't use `CLSID_ShellFolderView`. Start with `CLSID_ShellWindows` instead, asking for the [`IShellWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/exdisp/nn-exdisp-ishellwindows) interface, and go from there.