# Get Active Window of .net application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have an application named ProLaunch.exe. I want to get the active window in it and close it if the user is not performing any operation for the speicified period. A timer in the application will be used for this purpose.

How can I get the active window and close it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use the Win32 API [GetActiveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this.  This should work in both Forms and WPF apps.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, IntPtr msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;

// close the active window using API        
private void FindAndCloseActiveWindow()
{
 IntPtr handle=GetActiveWindow();
 SendMessage(handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
}
```

Comment: Will GetActiveWindow work for both modal and modaless dialogs?

Comment: Under the hood, dialogs are just windows so I don't see why not.  As long as the windows belong to your app, it should work. If you're looking to close windows outside your app then you'll need a different approach.

Comment: I need to close the window only if the form is not derived from a particular class. Is that possible?

Comment: Second parameter of `SendMessage` should be `IntPtr`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Form.ActiveForm
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx