# Get the path name of an focused file or directory on a linux system

Tags: linux, xfce

It is possible to get the path name of an focused file or directory on a linux system (xfce4 environment) ?

I am looking for something like this answer from MUG4N ([Get selected items of folder with WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382946/get-selected-items-of-folder-with-winapi/3400348#3400348)). Or even better a shell script solution.

There is the [xdotool](http://dev.man-online.org/man1/xdotool/) but i only find options for active windows and not for focused items.