# Get path to selected files in active explorer window

Tags: rust, windows-rs

Im trying get the path to the files which are selected in the currently active explorer window. [Similar to this example in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590086/c-sharp-get-the-windows-explore-path-which-has-the-focus) or [this example in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500504/python-get-path-of-selected-file-in-current-windows-explorer).
In the internet I found out, that you can use windows-rs to do things with win32.

But I only manage to write following code:

```
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::*;

use std::{thread, time, str};

fn main() {
    // wait to let me select the explorer window
    let ten_millis = time::Duration::from_millis(2000);
    thread::sleep(ten_millis);

    // get foreground window and check if it is an explorer window
    let handle = unsafe { GetForegroundWindow() };
    let buff = &mut [0; 100];
    unsafe { GetWindowModuleFileNameA(handle, buff)};

    let encoded = str::from_utf8_mut(buff).unwrap();

    let path = encoded.replace("\0", "");

    println!("{:?}", path);

    if path == "C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe" {
        // get folders?
    }
}
```

With this code I still have the problem that I only get the path from the rust exe while all other programs output an empty buffer.

I also couldn't get any further with it. I found *IShellFolderViewDual2* in the docs but haven't found a way to use it with the hwnd of the active window.

Comment: This is not how you'd retrieve the folder currently displayed in an Explorer window instance. See [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 1: Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130610-00/?p=4133) on how to navigate the confusing programming interface.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for your answer. But I still can't get it to work. If I interpret the code of Raymond Chen correctly. I should be able to get all open ShellWindows with *QueryActiveShellView*  which is located under *windows::Win32::UI::Shell::IShellBrowser* according to the doc. But I can't even import the Shell. Am I missing something?

Comment: You probably forgot to select the appropriate features. If you look at the [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/UI/Shell/struct.IShellBrowser.html) you'll see the required features (`"Win32_UI_Shell"`, `"Win32_System_Ole"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little known, Explorer (both Internet Explorer and File Explorer) in Windows have a common programming interface that lets you access all sorts of information, including the currently viewed folder location (in case of File Explorer).

While [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model) is a fairly awesome technology, its documentation is generally not. You'll find all sorts of interfaces documented, in isolation, but there is little to no conceptual coverage. This leads to a situation, where navigating interface hierarchies is like a walk in a maze. You won't get far without a scout. Luckily, Raymond Chen knows a fair bit of the Shell's internals, and frequently shares this information<sup>1</sup>.

The following is a rough translation of part 1 into Rust using the [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate. The code is using version 0.39.0, and while the library is still evolving some things may need to be changed in future versions.

The innermost function takes an `IShellBrowser` interface and extracts the currently selected folder:

```rust
fn get_location_from_view(browser: &IShellBrowser) -> Result<Vec<u16>> {
    let shell_view = unsafe { browser.QueryActiveShellView() }?;
    let persist_id_list: IPersistIDList = shell_view.cast()?;
    let id_list = unsafe { persist_id_list.GetIDList() }?;

    let mut item = MaybeUninit::<IShellItem>::uninit();
    unsafe { SHCreateItemFromIDList(id_list, &IShellItem::IID, addr_of_mut!(item) as _) }?;
    let item = unsafe { item.assume_init() };

    let ptr = unsafe { item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING) }?;

    // Copy UTF-16 string to `Vec<u16>` (including NUL terminator)
    let mut path = Vec::new();
    let mut p = ptr.0 as *const u16;
    loop {
        let ch = unsafe { *p };
        path.push(ch);
        if ch == 0 {
            break;
        }
        p = unsafe { p.add(1) };
    }

    // Cleanup
    unsafe { CoTaskMemFree(ptr.0 as _) };
    unsafe { CoTaskMemFree(id_list as _) };

    Ok(path)
}
```

There's a lot of magic going on here. I can't explain why that is how it needs to be done, but I can at least comment on some of the rough edges of the Rust code:

While I'm not aware of a way to create an `IShellItem` interface initialized from a null pointer, I went on to declare it as `MaybeUninit<IShellItem>` instead, and used [`addr_of_mut!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/macro.addr_of_mut.html) to pass its address to the C function `SHCreateItemFromIDList`. When that returns successfully, `item` can be assumed initialized (following core COM rules).

There's a slight window where the function can leak the memory allocated from `GetIDList` and `GetDisplayName`. The solution would be to wrap those pointers inside `#[repr(transparent)]` tuple-like structs with a [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) implementation that calls `CoTaskMemFree`. I might revisit this to make it not leak (though leaking resources isn't considered a safety issue in Rust).

The next piece of code takes an `IDispatch` interface representing an Explorer instance, and attempts to get the specific interface that represents the File Explorer's address bar:

```rust
fn get_browser_info<'a, P>(unk: P, hwnd: &mut HWND) -> Result<Vec<u16>>
where
    P: Into<InParam<'a, IUnknown>>,
{
    let shell_browser: IShellBrowser =
        unsafe { IUnknown_QueryService(unk, &SID_STopLevelBrowser) }?;
    *hwnd = unsafe { shell_browser.GetWindow() }?;

    get_location_from_view(&shell_browser)
}
```

The generic type `P` is just a convenient way to have the `IDispatch` interface automatically converted into an `IUnknown` as required by `IUnknown_QueryService`. This function also queries for the native `HWND` that's backing the specific Explorer instance. If you want to filter you could compare it to the return value of `GetForegroundWindow`, for example.

The following part is the main driver:

```rust
fn dump_windows(windows: &IShellWindows) -> Result<()> {
    let unk_enum = unsafe { windows._NewEnum() }?;
    let enum_variant = unk_enum.cast::<IEnumVARIANT>()?;
    loop {
        let mut fetched = 0;
        let mut var: [VARIANT; 1] = [VARIANT::default(); 1];
        let hr = unsafe { enum_variant.Next(&mut var, &mut fetched) };
        // No more windows?
        if hr == S_FALSE || fetched == 0 {
            break;
        }
        // Not an IDispatch interface?
        if unsafe { var[0].Anonymous.Anonymous.vt } != VT_DISPATCH.0 as _ {
            continue;
        }

        // Get the information
        let mut hwnd = Default::default();
        let location = get_browser_info(
            unsafe {
                var[0]
                    .Anonymous
                    .Anonymous
                    .Anonymous
                    .pdispVal
                    .as_ref()
                    .unwrap()
            },
            &mut hwnd,
        )?;

        // Convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 for display
        let location = String::from_utf16_lossy(&location);
        println!("Explorer location: \"{}\"", location);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

This is taking an `IShellWindows` interface, and iterating over the list of instances, one item at a time. If it finds an entry that holds an `IDispatch` interface, it passes it on to `get_browser_info` (see above).

`VARIANT`s are pretty complex types, and the `windows` crate represents them *very* accurately. The resulting code is pretty unwieldy, though I suppose this is a point where the `windows` crate sees room for improvements. I'm also pretty sure that the code is leaking the interface borrowed from `pdispVal`, though I haven't had time yet to look into this in detail. Leaking interfaces is more serious than leaking, for example, memory, so this is something I will have to come back to later.

Finally, the main entry point:

```rust
fn main() -> Result<()> {
    unsafe {
        CoInitializeEx(
            ptr::null(),
            COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE,
        )
    }?;

    let windows: IShellWindows =
        unsafe { CoCreateInstance(&ShellWindows, None, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER) }?;
    dump_windows(&windows)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

This initializes the thread into the STA, which is required for the remaining code. Another detail worth pointing out: `CoCreateInstance` needs to instantiate the `ShellWindows` object into the `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER`; if you instead passed `CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER`, the call would fail with `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG`.

The remainder is just your usual boilerplate. That includes both the imports as well as the *Cargo.toml* file. If you cannot import a particular type, you're probably missing the respective feature in the *Cargo.toml* file.

```rust
use std::{
    mem::MaybeUninit,
    ptr::{self, addr_of_mut},
};

use windows::{
    core::{IUnknown, InParam, Interface, Result},
    Win32::{
        Foundation::{HWND, S_FALSE},
        System::{
            Com::{
                CoCreateInstance, CoInitializeEx, CoTaskMemFree, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED, COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE, VARIANT,
            },
            Ole::{IEnumVARIANT, VT_DISPATCH},
        },
        UI::Shell::{
            IPersistIDList, IShellBrowser, IShellItem, IShellWindows, IUnknown_QueryService,
            SHCreateItemFromIDList, SID_STopLevelBrowser, ShellWindows,
            SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING,
        },
    },
};
```

```ini
[package]
name = "explorer_selection"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.39.0"
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_System_Com",
    "Win32_System_Ole",
    "Win32_UI_Shell",
    "Win32_UI_Shell_Common",
]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *References:*

- [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 1: Enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130610-00/?p=4133)
- [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 2: Tracking navigations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130613-00/?p=4093)
- [A big little program: Monitoring Internet Explorer and Explorer windows, part 3: Tracking creation and destruction](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130614-00/?p=4083)

Comment: First of thank you very much for your answer. This really helps me.
But if I compare the foreground window hwnd to the shell_browser.GetWindow() their not the same. 

Code: 

`let actual_window = unsafe { shell_browser.GetWindow() }?;

let foreground_window = unsafe { GetForegroundWindow() };

println!("Foreground: {:?}", foreground_window);

println!("Actual: {:?}", hwnd);`

Do I need to do anything else to compare them?

Comment: I hadn't verified this. It appears that `shell_browser.GetWindow()` returns a child window of the File Explorer instance. To get to the top-level window you can call `GetAncestor`, e.g. `let hwnd = shell_browser.GetWindow()?; let top_level = GetAncestor(hwnd, GA_ROOT);`. That should return a window handle you can compare against the return value from `GetForegroundWindow`.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'll see if I can package all this madness into a crate with an interface that doesn't look like a creation of Victor Frankenstein.